# How can I make my qpid queues persistent?

Tags: qpid

We have recently installed version 1.39.0 of the qpid C++ broker on a CentOS 7 server. The following RPMs have been installed:

```
pmena@server=> rpm -qa | grep qpid
qpid-proton-c-0.33.0-1.el7.x86_64
qpid-cpp-client-1.39.0-1.el7.x86_64
qpid-tests-1.37.0-5.el7.noarch
python2-qpid-1.37.0-5.el7.noarch
qpid-qmf-1.39.0-1.el7.x86_64
qpid-tools-1.39.0-1.el7.noarch
qpid-cpp-server-1.39.0-1.el7.x86_64
python2-qpid-qmf-1.39.0-1.el7.x86_64
qpid-cpp-client-docs-1.39.0-1.el7.noarch
```

We can add queues with the `durable` attribute, but after stopping and restarting qpidd, the queues disappear. When restoring the queues via the `qpid-config add queue` command, any statistical information associated with the queue is lost. Why are the queues - and their associated statistics - not persisting between restarts?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that adding the `qpid-cpp-server-linearstore-1.39.0-1.el7.x86_64` package from the CentOS repo gave us the functionality we were seeking. We were able to test this by creating some test traffic, observing the increased queue message and byte counts, and then restarting qpid. The queue message and byte counts were intact.

Comment: Great, this comes with Persistent module
Just in case anyone looking to install it on CentOS/RHEL:
yum -y install epel-release
yum -y install qpid-cpp-server-linearstore.x86_64 qpid-tools